# problema stof c++

Tags: c++, string, float

estoy realizando un programa un tengo un problema en la parte en la que convierto un string a float. Ya que estoy leyendo un archivo muy grande de csv y es posible que los segmentos que recoja no sean validos, por ello quiero que cuando salte la exepción me cambie un boolean a false y siga el código pero lo que ocurre es que el programa se detiene. ¿Que puedo hacer?

Los archivos csv tienen el formato:

```
NIF;clave;nombre;dirección;latitud;longitud,,;frase

10982609X;pU7Pqqk;Marlie Klassmann;1133 Blaine Place;37,10422;-8,308;¡Intentemos algo!
```

segment es de tipo vector y en las posiciones 4 y 5 se encuentran la latitud y longitud (float)

```
        try {
        latitud = stof(segment[4]);
        //segment es de tipo vector<string>
        if (latitud > maxlat) {
            maxlat = latitud;
        }

        if (latitud < minlat) {
            minlat = latitud;
        }
        longitud = stof(segment[5]);
        if (longitud > maxlon) {
            maxlon = longitud;
        }

        if (longitud < minlon) {
            minlon = longitud;
        }
    } catch (const char *exception) {
        datosValidos = false;
    }
```

La salida es RUN FAIL ERROR

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stof

RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 315ms)
```

Comment: estaría genial que indicases de qué tipo es `segment` y qué valores hay en las posiciones 4 y 5

Comment: vale ya he hecho esas modificaciones

Comment: El separador de decimales debería ser un punto, no una coma, yo creo que es eso lo que te está fallando

Answer (score 0):

El separador de decimales que espera `strtof` es el punto, no la coma. Por eso te falla la conversión.

Debes reemplazar un caracter por otro antes de llamar a `strtof`:

```
bool replace(std::string& str, std::string const& from, std::string const& to)  
{
    size_t start_pos = str.find(from);
    if(start_pos == std::string::npos)
        return false;
    str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
    return true;
}

// ...

replace(segment[4], ",", ".");
latitud = stof(segment[4]);
```

Comment: he probado cambiar las comas por puntos pero sigue sin funcionarme

Comment: @AdrianAmaro prueba a hacer un cout de los dos valores de segment a ver si alguno tiene valores raros

Comment: lo he hecho y parece que todo esta normal, no hay números raros.

Comment: @AdrianAmaro el cout no debes hacerlo indiscriminadamente sino en el catch, para imprimir únicamente el valor que te está dando problemas